# flutter release apk not accepted by google with error: the app should not have debug sign key

Tags: flutter, dart

I have followed the steps described here 
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android
to release my app. and here is my android/app/build.gradle release part:

```
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

       }
   }
```

and I have created the key.properties with the correct properties in my android folder of my project. but when I try to publish my app into Stores(not just googleplay) I use flutter build apk --release and I upload my file in stored. but I get this Error:

> the app should not have debug sign key

Comment: I have exactly the same setup and it works for me. Are you sure that you have the correct values in `keystoreProperties`?

Comment: did you do a `flutter clean` first?

Comment: thanks I should have done flutter clean